# React sharing behavior of external CSS file - body background for components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, html-tbody

how can I change React sharing behavior of an external CSS file in React, so I can set the body background different for different components?

login.css

```css
body {
  background-image: url('../../../images/bannerbackground.png');
}
```

home.css

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(185, 174, 160);
}
```

but for react's sharing behavior with the components of the same root I cannot differentiate it, is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a solution. Its pretty simple. To prevent the clashes you can implement CSS modules. Rename your CSS files to `filename.module.css`

Result:

```
// note the classname generated 
<button class="Button_error_ax7yz">Error Button</button>
```

> According to the official [repo](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) CSS Modules are “CSS files in which all class names and animation names are scoped locally by default”. What does this mean? CSS Modules are not specs or an implementation in the browser, but rather a process in a build step (with the help of Webpack or Browserify) that changes class names and selectors to be scoped (kinda like namespaced)

Comment: I just want to provide each component a different body style, But whenever I use body in any css file it extends it to all the components. If i use class I could catch that specific container just, I rather want to catch the whole body of a component.

Comment: Yes. So to prevent clashes just implement CSS modules. Your CSS is being clashed. You have to rename ```login.css``` to ```login.module.css``` and likewise same for other css files. It won't clash.